# Spring boot/ Datadog- Logs Show Info Status For Warnings Or Errors

Tags: java, spring-boot, slf4j, amazon-kinesis, datadog

I'm working with spring boot 2, java 11 and Datadog. I have this problem:
Logs Show Info Status For Warnings Or Errors.
https://docs.datadoghq.com/logs/guide/logs-show-info-status-for-warnings-or-errors/#define-a-log-status-remapper
The Datadog configuration is only failing to one service: The problem is the following:

The color of the log mismatches to the status: for instance:
sometimes the color is red and the status is ERROR(ok)
sometimes the color is red but the status is INFO(bad)

These are the dependencies related to logs:

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.9</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.9</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-over-slf4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.32</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.logstash.logback</groupId>
            <artifactId>logstash-logback-encoder</artifactId>
            <version>6.6</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>software.amazon.kinesis</groupId>
            <artifactId>amazon-kinesis-client</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.2</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                    <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>log4j</groupId>
                    <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
```

In datadog the log format to the service is:

```
%{date("HH:mm:ss.SSS"):timestamp}\s+\[%{data:thread}\]\s+%{word:status}\s+%{data.class}\s+-\s+%{data:message}
```

This is the logback:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>

    <appender name="CONSOLE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <encoder>
            <pattern>%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %level %logger{15} - %msg%n</pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>

    <root level="INFO">
        <appender-ref ref="CONSOLE" />
    </root>
    <logger name="software.amazon.kinesis">
        <level value="INFO"/>
    </logger>

</configuration>
```

Could you please give me any insight to solve it?